# Show only errors in Firefox development console

Tags: firefox, browser-console

Is it possible to show only 400 errors (or all errors) in the Firefox browser console?

There are usually a few hundred requests in a typical web page, most with 200 (OK) status. It'd save time by filtering those out to only display errors (400, 404, 403, 500 etc) which require investigation.

I know it is possible to sort by the Status column but filtering by Status number would be better in many cases.

[image: Filter out non-errors in Firefox console]

(Chrome once had such a filter but it no longer seems to exist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is something quite simple when you know where to look for. I too looked for it for a while before stumbling upont it by chance.

First thing, you need to locate dthe "Filter URLs" near the top of the Network Tab.

[image: Filter URLs box]

Then you just need to type in "404" and it should auto-suggest the insertion of "status-code:404". There you go, as simple as this.

[image]